# Reducing a nested loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm studying the Movielens dataset for a classification task, so I'm preparing my dataset as follows:

I have 3 datasets:

**genome-score.cvs:**

| movieId | tagId | relevance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.028749999999999998 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.0152749999 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.19627257 |

**Genome tag:**

| tagId | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 007 |
| 2 | 007 (series) |
| 3 | 18th century |

**and movies.csv:**

| movieId | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Toy Story (1995) |

Then I have a list of tag called: **GenTags**, in this list there are all tag that the people used for a tagging the films.

So my task is:

1. Insert as column in **movies.csv** all tag in **GenTags**
2. For each movies insert in corresponding cell the relevance of tag for that film.

This is the output that I want:

| movieId | title | 007 | 007 (series) | 18th century | 1920s | .... and all tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Toy Story (1995) | 0.3485 | 0.269 | 0.1907499999 | 0.20475 | 0.05675 |

This for prepare my dataset for a classification learning:
My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

GenTags = pd.read_csv('ml-25m/genome-tags.csv', sep=',')
GenScor = pd.read_csv('ml-25m/genome-scores.csv', sep=',')
Movies = pd.read_csv('NewMovies.csv', sep=',')


for tag in GenTags["tag"]:
    Movies[tag] = np.nan


for index, row in Movies.iterrows():
    for j in GenTags["tag"]:
        k = row["movieId"]
        A = GenScor[GenScor.movieId == k]
        i = GenTags[GenTags.tag == j]["tagId"].tolist()[0]
        B = A[A.tagId == i]["relevance"].tolist()
        if len(B) == 1:
            C = A[A.tagId == i]["relevance"].tolist()[0]
            Movies.loc[index, j] = C


Movies.to_csv("prove.csv",index=False)
```

**But this code is too computationally expensive. Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like a merge and pivot.  Merge scores to movies, then genome to that.

This operates under the assumption that all of the tag features you want in your model will appear at least once for at least one movie.  Any movie that doesn't have that tag gets the `fill_value`, or you could add a custom function for imputation.

```
import pandas as pd

score = pd.DataFrame({'movieId': [1, 1, 1], 'tagId': [1, 2, 3], 'relevance': [0.0287499999999999, 0.0152749999, 0.19627257]})
genome = pd.DataFrame({'tagId': [1, 2, 3], 'tag': ['007', '007 (series)', '18th century']})
movies = pd.DataFrame({'movieId': [1], 'title': ['Toy Story (1995)']})

df = movies.merge(score,on='movieId')
df = df.merge(genome, on='tagId')

df =df.pivot_table(index=['movieId','title'], columns='tag', values='relevance', fill_value=0).reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1)
```

Output

```
   movieId             title      007  007 (series)  18th century
0        1  Toy Story (1995)  0.02875      0.015275      0.196273
```

Comment: Thanks Man it works

Comment: Awesome. Feel free to accept it as the answer if it solved your problem! Cheers.